# Parsing a HTML string

Tags: php

I have folling HTML string in a variable (simplified)

```
<div class="parent">
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
</div>
```

Now I have set a new structure like:

```
<div class="parent">
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <div class="special">
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    </div>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
</div>
```

How do I parse this with php? I have looked at DOMDocument but can't find a method to do this.

The problem is, with DOMDocument or with simpleHTML: I need to change the DOM structure. I do not a find a method to do this.

Example code (in $output is the first HTML string above):

```
$doc= new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($output);
    
$items=$doc->getElementsByTagName('figure');
foreach ($items as $item){
        // Now i am on the figure node, here I can do something like:
        // $doc->appendChild
        // or $doc->createAttribute
        // But I have to add a div above two nodes.
}
```

I need to "sum up" every second and third figure into a new div. But how I can do this with DOMDocument  or simpleHTML?
I would like to break the DOM structure into a new one. Maybe my approach with the DOM is wrong, and it can be solved differently?

Comment: What do you mean with parse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other approach is to parse the output on string level. I have written like so:

```
// Parse output in gallery and figures
$gallery = strstr($output, '<figure', true);
$figures = strstr($output, '<figure');

// Split figure in array
$pattern="/<figure/";
$fig_arr=preg_split($pattern,$figures);
$fig_arr=array_filter($fig_arr); // Remove empty entries

// Loop thru the array
$item_count=1;
$figures_return="";
foreach ($fig_arr as $item){
    if (is_int(($item_count - 1) / 3)){
        // every fourth item
        $figures_return.="<figure$item\n";
    } else if (is_int(($item_count - 2) / 3)){
        // every third item
        $figures_return.="<div><figure$item\n";
    } else if (is_int(($item_count - 3) / 3)){
        // every second item
        $figures_return.="<figure$item</div>\n";
    } else {
        // first item
        $figures_return.="<figure$item\n";
    }
    $item_count++;
}

// Combinte return value
$return_value="$gallery\n$figures_return\n";
```

Is not that elegant, but it works.

This makes the output:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div class="gallery">
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <div>
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    </div>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <div>
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any remarks to this string-parsing approach?

Answer (score 0):

I am using PHP Simple HTML Dom for parsing: https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/

```
// Create a DOM object from a string
$html = str_get_html('<div class="parent">
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <div class="special>
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
        <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    </div>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
    <figure class="item"><img></figure>
</div>');

// Example -> is similar with jQuery accessing the DOM
echo $html->find("div.parent div.special figure img", 0);
```

Comment: With Simple HTML I have the same problem as with DOMDocument, I don't know how to change the DOM sturcture. I have extended my question with this information.